Idiomatic way to switch between object methods
In my C++ program, I have multiple instances where I am trying to find some property given an std::string name. 
One of the times where I need to find one of these properties is in a class method, and the property I need to find is a method of one of the class members, something like:
struct Bar {
  SomeClass obj;
  int doSomething(std::string input) {
    if (input == "a") {
      return obj.a();
    } else if (input == "b") {
      return obj.b();
    }
    ...
  }
}

and I cannot modify the definition of SomeClass.
There are many similar instances in other parts of my code, but they simply return integers instead of needing to call another method.
My question is as follows: what is the best-practice way to implement this to avoid a bunch of conditional statements from cluttering the code?

"and the property I need to find is a method of one of the class members" what does that mean? How is the second example related to the first? You say you want to avoid "a buch of conditional statements" and "having many different maps", but you do not show them. It is very difficult to help you avoid writing code when you do not show that code. It isnt really obvious what you want to avoid.

How are Foo and Bar joined? Why is Foo even mentioned?

Somehow I smell a XY problem. It is not clear to me what the actual problem you need to solve is.

C++ predates reflection and adding reflection hasn't been a particularly high priority because C++ is all about speed and runtime reflection... Not very speedy.

it looks like you started from some concrete issue but then tried to make it too general. The main effect is that the question is very difficult to understand. This is much simpler if you show a very concrete example, we can answer, and then very likely you will see how you can apply the answers also in other cases

A map of names-to-lambda expressions is probably the best you're going to get, but first make sure you aren't accidentally shooting yourself in the foot with a too-complicated solution or sticking your hand into the "But this is how I do it in Python!" trap.

As far as I am aware, there is no common-practice way to store a method of a different class in a class. There certainly is such a method, it's called pointer-to-member function. Although, as other commenters mentioned, it's unlikely that you should be using it, rather you should rethink your design to get rid of passing method's name as string.

Strings are useful for: input, output, data storage. In almost every other case they should not be used. Instead, use enums, data objects, object references, and so on (it seems like you've done something like this in Python or Ruby, but it's not a very good idea there either).

@JohnBayko I am given a string as input, and that is unchangeable. Should I create a map from string to int and then proceed from there instead?

@NYcan Ideally, at the point of input a string should be converted to an internal representation. The main reason is that you know the value is always valid after that, but a string can be anything (bad input, changed by a bug, misspelled, etc.). A secondary reason is the internal value can be an object if you want, inherited from a class but implemented so the methods make sense (e.g AClass::doSomething() and BClass::doSomething() do what SomeClass::a() and SomeClass::b() do in your example).

QT implements something similar https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/metaobjects.html - but it's way too complex solution to your problem, just FYI.

Even though I tend to agree with @DevSolar's comment that this seems like a XY problem, one option would be to map string keys to function pointers, as in:
struct Bar {
  SomeClass obj;
  std::map<std::string, int (SomeClass::*)()> methodMap = {
      {"a", &SomeClass::a},
      {"b", &SomeClass::b},
  };

  int doSomething(std::string input) {
    if (methodMap.count(input)) {
      return (obj.*methodMap[input])();
    } else {
      return -1;
    }
  }
}

Note that the else { return -1; } block is a very basic way to handle unmapped "strings" (keys).

unless the functions are static they will not have the type int (*)() but instead int (SomeClass::*)()

In addition to the comment by @NathanOliver, that’s not the correct syntax for calling through a pointer-to-member-function. Should be return (obj.*methodMap[input])();.

Why is the function suddenly receiving a SomeClass argument by value instead of using the OP's existing attribute of Foo?

thanks NathanOliver, Pete Becker, and ShadowRanger for the polite suggestions, and @user4581301 for the impolite one.

Yeah the idea is good, but you don't use the correct syntax to call the pointer to member function. In this example it should be return (obj.*methodMap[input])();. Also returning -1 is arguably a C-style error handling, in C++ you can just throw an exception (but OK, that's a bit opinion-based).

@pptaszni you're right, I didn't have time to test that. thanks for pointing it out!

It's 7 years since C++17 introduced std::invoke(methodMap[input], obj);, we can get rid of .*

Not trying to be impolite. Compared to std::function, a method pointer is very stupid. That stupidity makes a method pointer fast (good possibility of lower overhead) when it can be used, but it is very easy to get wrong.
